# resuming a dag runs immediately with the last scheduled execution

Tags: airflow

After pausing a dag for 2-3 days, when resuming the dag with catchup=False, will run immediately  with the last execution.
For example a dag that sends data to an external system is scheduled to run everyday on 19:00.
Stopping the dag for 4 days and enabling on 11:00 would run the dag immediately with yesterdays execution and then again on 19:00 for that day.
In this case the dag runs two times on the day it's resumed.

Is it possible to resume the dag and the first run will happen actually on 19:00?

Answer (score 0):

With default operators, we cannot achieve what you are expecting. Closest to that, what airflow has is [LatestOnlyOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_modules/airflow/operators/latest_only_operator.html). This is one of the simplest Operators and needs only following configuration

```
latest_only = LatestOnlyOperator(task_id='latest_only')
```

This would let the downstream tasks run only if the `current time` falls between `current execution date` and `next execution date`. So,  in your case, it would skip execution of three days, but yesterday's run would trigger the jobs.